# Locale/Internationalization in django

Tags: python, django

I realize there is a utility django.utils.translation that will translate "Hello" in "Hola" somehow but I wanted more control over the exact translations.

Right now my django project is achieving multilingual support with a View.py wrapper for render with some logic to determine the user's preferred locale or falling back to a default locale.

My templates are currently in this type of structure:

```
templates/en_US/index.html
templates/es_MX/index.html
```

with some logic that will let it fall back to templates/en_US/index.html if, say, templates/pt_PT/index.html doesn't exist.

I want to create a custom tag/function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/) in my template layer that can translate a token to a string so I can move away from maintaining a set of template files for each locale. For example:

```
<h2> {% t 'index.welcome' %} </h2>
```

in en-US it would become:

```
<h2> Welcome </h2>
```

in es-MX it would become:

```
<h2> Hola </h2>
```

So I thought I could to this like this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def t(token):
    # determine locale and look up the token and get its value
    # in the appropriate locale file (with some fall-back logic)
```

But I don't have access to the request object in a registered tag so I can't determine what I need to find the locale.

Comment: It seems to me that you are recreating the Django translation mechanisms with perhaps even less control over the translations. Is there a reason you really need to? With the builtins, you could do `{% trans 'index.welcome' %}`, and then provide your translations in the .po files. Or just leave it as `{% trans 'Welcome' %}` and your fallback to en-US is already built in.

Comment: Sounds like I need to read more documentation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this functionality, and more, is already provided by Django's Internationalization framework, as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/

Translations in templates, specifically, are done by way of the trans template tag, such as `{% trans 'Welcome' %}`.

(As mentioned in my comment above)